# Type parameter which inherits from a certain abstract

Tags: c#, game-engine

I was wondering if there is a way to pass in a type which is enforced to be of a certain base type. For instance, for my game engine I have a attribute list (controllable, rigidBody, etc). I have a addAttribute parameter which takes a new object. However, I would like to also have an overload which takes a type instead from which I can create a new object on my own. So for instance

```
public void addAttribut(Type attribute)
```

I am thinking of maybe something that implements linq? I have tried but it looks like "where" can be only used on generics:

```
public void addAttribute(Type attribute) where attribute : Attribute
```

would be the signature of the function. I believe that Unity does this; however it could be that it can do this through Mono.

I could always throw an exception if it is not of the correct base type. However I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the programmer from passing in the wrong time all together.

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy for calling code to need to know the type at *compile-time*, you could make it a generic method with a type parameter:

```
public void AddAttribute<T>() where T : Attribute
{
    // Use typeof(T)
}
```

Or to enforce a parameterless constructor which you can then call:

```
public void AddAttribute<T>() where T : Attribute, new()
{
    T t = new T();
    ...
}
```

But otherwise there's no way of doing it, no - you'd have to validate the argument at execution time, just like any other.

Comment: Hah! Perfect now I remember how Unity does this (haven't used it in quite a while!)

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer to this, this will work lacing your functions together public void addAttribute<T>() where T : Attribute, new(), thus you can now call addAttribute(new T());

Comment: @SergueiFedorov: It wasn't clear that you wanted to create an instance using a parameterless constructor; for example, you might want other constructors. I'll edit my answer to clarify.